# Dynamic cast to vector iterator

Tags: c++, casting

I have below snippet-

```
std::vector<cMyClass> myCls = GetClassValues();
std::vector<cMyClass>::const_iterator imyCls;
for( imyCls = myCLs.begin(); imyCls != myCls.end(); ++imyCls)
{
  cMyClass *cls = dynamic_cast<cMyClass*>(*imyCls);//C2682


}
```

In for loop I want to have pointer variable of cMyClass, I can't use direct assignment or static cast. SO using dynamic_cast but that also doesn't seem to be working.

What option I have if I want to make it working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
cMyClass *cls = &*imyCls;
```

`*imyCls` is a reference to the object in the `vector`; `&*imyCls` is the address of that.

Answer (score 1):

At first, you try to get pointer from reference, you must add `&` before iterator dereferencing like this: `&*myCls`. Also, since you are using const_iterator, you can get const pointer only. Either change `imyCls` to non-const iterator, or change cast to const pointer version.

```
cMyClass const *cls = dynamic_cast<cMyClass const*>(&*imyCls);
```